# Convertir String a unicode y viceverse

Tags: javascript

Por qué este código no me funciona? Lo que quiero lograr es convertir una string a formato unicode

```js
var clanes = [];

var txt = "Hola";
var to = "";
var c = txt.split('');

for(var i=1; i<txt.length; i++) {
  
   to += txt.charCodeAt(i);
 
 
  
}

to = parseInt(to);
var d = String.fromCharCode(to);

console.info(to);
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "String a Unicode"? Unicode se aplica a símbolos (letras, dígitos, emoticonos de flamenca), no a Strings. Lo que tienes en el `to` son los Unicodes de las tres últimas letras del String (te falta la primera) pero eso no lo convierte en "Unicode de 'ola'"

Comment: Otro ejemplo, los Unicodes concatenados de "la" es `10897`, que es ⪑ (https://unicode-table.com/es/search/?q=10897)

Comment: A lo que me refiero es charCodeAt, pero como la función inversa, osea envez de que me devuelva la letra, que me devuelva la string completa de todas las letras unidas

Comment: Y si a esa función le pasas `10897`.... ¿cómo esperas que esa función adivine que la cadena original era `la` y no `⪑`, o `&#10;&#8;&#9;&#7;`? No sólo la función que pides no existe (¿por qué tendría que existir cualquier función que se te ocurra a tí, por cierto? Y más teniendo en cuenta que, como he explicado más arriba, no tiene sentido) sino que además no hay una relación biyectiva que permita recuperar la cadena original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya puestos en faena, lo escribo como respuesta:

1. La función que pides no existe. Por el simple hecho de que a tí se te ocurra que la necesitas no significa que vaya a venir ya definida por el lenguaje, para eso se pueden definir nuevas funciones.
2. La función que pides no tiene sentido. Unicode asigna un valor numérico a cada símbolo. Es una relación de símbolos a números. Un String NO es un símbolo, es una colección de símbolos. NO HAY UN UNICODE PARA STRINGS.

   Concatenar los unicodes de los Strings no es equivalente. El ejemplo de los comentarios; concatenar los valores de `l` y `a` no es "el Unicode de `la`".
3. La función que pides no puede funcionar correctamente. Al concatenar los números tienes una cadena de números, pero a esa cadena de números se puede llegar desde varios String de origen distintos. Para el valor `10897` puede venir de la concatenacion de `la`, o de `⪑`, o de `&#10;&#8;&#9;&#7;`; todas las cuales son opciones válidas. ¿Cómo se supone que la función adivinará el valor original?.

Dicho lo dicho, si quieres implementar TÚ la función, no hay más que poner un símbolo entre los distintos valores de Unicodes para poder obtener las letras originales; si por ejemplo pones un espacio, puedes implementar la función que tome "108 97", separe el String por el espacio y recupere la letra correspondiente a cada valor. Pero nada de función predefinida, nada de "Unicode de String" y nada de "mezclarlo todo y ver qué pasa".